# load balancing my application

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing

I want to setup a loadbalancer with 2 machines. The loadbalancer should reside on one machine and split load between itself and other machine (with a greater percentage of request hitting other machine). There is no issue of cookie and session, since every request is independent. Also I have given my client an IP address (something like http://99.99.9.9/aaa.php ) not a domain name so I want the request coming to that IP to be load balanced. Both my machines are VPS residing on linode. How do I configure apache mod proxy balancer(if its possible that way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAProxy is great, I've used this quite a bit: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

Pound is another one: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pound

I now use Zeus (With Joyent) and can't recommend it enough: http://www.zeus.com/products/load-balancer/index.html

As for mod_proxy, I wouldn't recommend it.  But here is a tutorial if you'd still like to pursue it: http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/LoadBalancingWithModProxy

Comment: thnx...how do i configure it to split load between self and another machine?

Comment: Each of those load balancers listed has documentation on that.  The link I posted for mod_proxy also tells you how to do it.

Comment: 1 more thing how do I make it run on startup?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for mod proxy balancer, but [Linux Virtual Server](http://www.linux-vs.org/) will do everything you have asked for above.